# If you have 4 blue balls and 5 red balls, in how many ways can you form a group of 5 balls that must contain at least 2 red balls?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I thought of doing it this way:
Since there will be four cases, we just consider each one and then just add the results up in the end.
Case 1: You have exactly $2$ red balls and $3$ blue balls. The number of groups is $P(5,2) \cdot P(4, 3)= 480$.
Case 2: You have exactly $3$ red balls and $2$ blue balls. The number of groups is $P(5,3) \cdot P(4, 2)=720$.
Case 3: You have exactly $4$ red balls and $1$ blue ball. The number of groups is $P(5,4) \cdot P(4, 1)=480$.
Case 4: You have $5$ red balls and no blue balls. You only have one possible group.
Adding up all the results, you get 1201 possible groups.   Order doesn't matter here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I left out a part of the question. The group must have five balls in total.

Comment: In Case 4, it seems to me there is only one possible group, not 120; namely, the group containing all 5 of the red balls. Unless order matters, which is not at all clear from the way the problem is stated in the title. If your groups **are** ordered selections, then it seems to me you're undercounting. In Case 1, $P(5,2)P(4,3)=480$ is just the number of ordered selections containing 2 red and 3 blue balls, such that ***all the red balls come before all the blue balls***. If red and blue balls can come in any order, I get 4800 possibilities for Case 1.

Comment: Assuming order doesn't matter, would it then be $480+720+1=1201$ possible groups?

Comment: Assuming that a "group" is just a combination (i.e. an unordered set) of balls, I get $$\binom52\binom43+\binom53\binom42+\binom54\binom41+\binom44\binom40=10\cdot4+10\cdot6+5\cdot4+1\cdot1=121.$$

Comment: @A.Berok No, it seems to be $C(5,2)C(4,3) + C(5,3)C(4,2) + C(5, 4)C(4,1)+C(5,5)C(4,0) = 121$

Comment: @A.Berok think about it, how many ways can you form up a group of five out of 9? With the Binomial coefficient you get 126. I think you did something wrong with the calculations

Comment: Since there are $\binom95=126$ possible combinations of $5$ balls with no restrictions, and there are just $5$ combinations with $\lt5$ red balls (take all the blue balls and any one of the five red balls), the answer to your problem is $126-5=121.$

Comment: Does it count as a "different way" to take the same five balls in a different orders? Does it count as a "different way" to swap out one selected ball for another ball of the same color?

Comment: @bof So, these combinations that you must subtract are essentially the ones that don't fit the rule. I can think of the cases where there are all blue balls and the case where there are four blue balls and one red ball. Besides these cases, though, which others can you subtract?

Comment: There is no case with "all blue balls" because there are only 4 blue balls and a group has to have 5 balls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the balls does not matter when choosing the balls in the problem, so you should be using combinations instead of permutations when solving the problem. Thus, the correct answer should be $$C(5,2)C(4,3)+C(5,3)C(4,2)+C(5,4)C(4,1)+C(5,5)C(4,0)=121$$.